# Question with tried Eigenvalues of Laplacian operator and Sobolev spaces III.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, spectral-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^d$ and let $g\in L^2(\Omega )$. 
 Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be the eigenvalues of the Laplacian operator $\Delta$, and $(e_n)_n$ the eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalues.
There exist a unique $u=(u_t)\in C^0([0,+\infty [,L^2(\Omega ))$ that solves the problem
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}−\Delta u=0 ,\in D′(]0,+\infty [\times \Omega),\quad u_0=g,\quad u_t\in H^1_0(\Omega )$$
with $u_t=\sum^{+\infty }_{n=1}e^{−λ_nt}(g,e_n) e_n$

My question is how we prove that
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}−\Delta u=0 ,\in D′(]0,+\infty [\times \Omega) ?$$
i.e. For all $\psi \in C^{\infty}_c(\I \times \Omega), \quad \langle \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\Delta u \rangle_{D',D} = 0$$
We write $u_t$ for $u(.,t)$.

I tried this:

$$\Delta u(t)=\Delta \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} [e^{-\lambda_n t} (g,e_n)e_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda_n t} (g,e_n) (-\lambda_n) e_n$$

Let $\psi \in C^{\infty}_c(I \times \Omega)$; We have: 
$$(\dfrac{d}{dt} u(t),\psi)=-(u(t),\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial t})$$
My problem is to conclude that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(I \times \Omega)$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried to edit your question.  But do you want some assumption on $g$?  Maybe that it is $L^2$?  Also, is $\Omega$ any bounded subset, or do you want it open?  And what about the boundary conditions of $\Delta$.  Dirichlet maybe?  Also, maybe I took some liberties with the editing - please edit it back if I made mistakes.

Comment: There are only assuptions what i have in this problem.

Comment: If you substitute your formula for $u_t$ into the equation, and you don't mind interchanging the sums and the differential operators, it drops out rather quickly.  And considering the speed at which $e^{\lambda_n t}$ converges to zero as $n \to \infty$, the interchange shouldn't be so hard to justify.  I know this answer isn't rigorous.  But neither is your question.

Comment: Of course, my approach will require some kind of estimate on how fast the $\lambda_n$ grow.  Surely such results are standard, but probably require tighter hypotheses on the nature of $\Omega$.

Comment: But the equality must be prouved in the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'(]0,+\infty[\times \Omega)$.

Comment: And the hypothesis $g \in L^2(\Omega)$ must be implicit, otherwise what does $(g,e_n)$ mean?

Comment: $(.,.)$ note the product scalar on $L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: So, when you do the interchange between the summation and the differentiable operators, you think of the infinite sum as taking place in $D'$.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand votre idea.

Comment: In essence, you have to prove that if I apply both sides of your equation to $\varphi \in D$, then both sides are the same.

Comment: Yes, how we prouve it?

Comment: Are you allowed to assume $\frac d{dt} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\lambda_n t} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n e^{\lambda_n t} a_n$ for any summable sequence $a_n$?  That seems to me to be the crux of your problem.  The rest is just writing out definitions.  Here $a_n = (g,e_n) (\varphi, e_n)$.

Comment: Why we have this assumption? And how this assumption will be help to the proof? Than'k for the help

Comment: And you begin with $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ or $\Delta t$?

Comment: So first - by $\Delta$, do you mean the sum of the second derivatives, or minus the sum of the second derivatives?  I think the question is inconsistent, and has some sign errors, which will change according to which definition of $\Delta$ you use.

Comment: Second, I think you should be able to simply things using $(\frac \partial{\partial t} u,\varphi) = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e_n,g) (e^{-\lambda_n t} e_n,\frac \partial{\partial t} \varphi)$.

Comment: Then reduce to the case $\varphi(x,t) = \alpha(t) \theta(x)$.  And then $(e^{-\lambda_n t} e_n, \frac\partial{\partial t} \varphi) = (e^{-\lambda_n t},\frac\partial{\partial t} \alpha) (e_n,\theta)$.  And $(e^{-\lambda_n t},\frac\partial{\partial t} \alpha)$ - well you just write out the integral and integrate by parts to see that it is $\lambda_n (e^{-\lambda_n t},\alpha)$.

Comment: But it is true that I have never taken an actual course in distribution theory, and so I don't know which obvious things you are allowed to assume and which ones you aren't.  But the very fact that the question is stated non-rigorously leads me to think that the answer should be allowed to be non-rigorous.  Anyway, my knowledge on the subject is now exhausted.

Comment: I edit my post so can any one help me please